# "Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider" not found

Tags: laravel, intervention

The whole project stops working after installing Intervention Image

The entire project stops working after installing Intervention Image.

I have a Windows system and XAMPP installed (just for information). I install a new Laravel project, and immediately start installing Intervenbtion Image. installs fine but as soon as I add in config/app.php -> providers: Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class

Everything will stop working. Error returned: Class "Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider" not found

I tried installing using package.json but the same thing.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Intervention Image v2 is [EOL- end of life](https://image.intervention.io/v2/introduction/installation) and has that `ImageServiceProvider`.

But in [upgrade guide](https://image.intervention.io/v3/introduction/upgrade) from v2 to v3, in **other changes** say:

> The service providers for the Laravel were removed to avoid a dependency to the framework and to highlight Intervention Image rather framework agnostic, which it always was.

Just follow [installation](https://image.intervention.io/v3/introduction/installation) by composer as they describe and follow the example for usage.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, My mistake, I didn’t look at the version I was working with.

Comment: @Coder mark as correct to help others :)